# PHP IMAP - getting the sent to email address - instead getting the 'default' email set in Exchange

Tags: php, email, imap, exchange-server

I have an Exchange server setup and accounts have email aliases.  For example foo@bar.com is the 'main' email and bar@bar.com is an alias for foo@bar.com.  If I send an email to the alias - bar@bar.com - in both Outlook (using Exchange protocol) and Thunderbird (set up using IMAP) if I look at the headers I can see that the email was sent to bar@bar.com.  However if I get the message using PHP's IMAP functions (for example imap_fetch_overview and imap_fetchheaders), it only returns the to: email as being foo@bar.com.  Is there a way using the PHP IMAP library to get the correct email address the email was sent to?